# JSP html form generation based on JDBC meta data

Tags: sql, jsp, jdbc, metadata

could anybody give me a good idea or hint (not a tool) how I could implement a JDBC meta data based automatic generation of html forms?
I have solved this before in a Java standalone program - now I want to expand the idea within html.
I do NOT want to use Spring, Wicket or JSF to solve the problem, I want to do it myown to learn from scratch.
I have searched really a lot, I found a lot of stuff, but nothing which could answer my question. But I am sure this problem has been solved in the past a dozen times.

Thank you
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) class, let it call your "Java standalone program" in the `doGet()` method, get the desired data in form of some `List<Row>` from it, put it in the request scope and forward the request to [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)

```
List<Row> rows = yourProgram.list();
request.setAttribute("rows", rows);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/list.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And finally in `/WEB-INF/list.jsp` use the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `c:forEach` to display it.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<table>
    <tr>
        <c:forEach items="${rows[0].columns}" var="column">
            <th><c:out value="${column.name}" /></th>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="row">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach items="${row.columns}" var="column">
                <td><input type="text" name="${fn:escapeXml(column.name)}" value="${fn:escapeXml(column.value)}" /></td>
            </c:ForEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Let it submit to a servlet by `<form method="post">` and gather the data in `doPost()` method.

Comment: thank you for this small piece of code; I also found one of your other examples which is very good.